# Are javascript templates only useful for inserting small items into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, templates

I recent came across Javascript templates and have become quite intrigued.

I am building a large PHP application using the MVC pattern. Templating is handled by the rather awesome [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

I recently came across a [javascript implementation of twig](https://github.com/schmittjoh/twig.js).

I have also read [quite](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/) [a](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Oct/13/Client-Templating-with-jQuery) [bit](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/javascript-templates-and-how-we-use-them-in-hifi) about using javascipt template engines.

Now, in my application, the application generates a the full page for standard requests as fallback for users without javascript. For AJAX requests, it can generate the content part of the page (no `<head>`, `<body>` etc).

The ajax response object is currently just a the rendered HTML content, which is then inserted into DOM.

Should I instead return a response object containing a compiled javascript template and the objects to be inserted into the template? What are the benefits of doing that?

From the posts I have read, the javascript templates were only small snippets representing a small part of a page, for example displaying a comment on a blog post during the instant that the user has submitted it.

Are javascript templates only useful for inserting these sort of small "pieces" in a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

A recent project I was on got "client-side template fever" and we used the dang things for every single template.

With every template library I've used (which is two or three), the error messages you get are not very good. If you have a huge template that operates on a fair amount of data, you'll quickly find the `u.foo is null or not an object` error message increasingly frustrating.

The best-practices I've settled on is:

- Return a full HTML snippet (from the server) if it's a template that is seldom loaded. If you are only loading that HTML once on a page, then you might as well send it down populated right? This also encourages you to keep your logic up on the server, where it probably belongs.
- Use client-side templates for *small, repeated* templates. Your blog comment example is probably a good one. I've found the most success when my client-side templates are pretty small (< 10 lines)
- Use a logic-less template engine. The more logic allowable in a template, the harder they are to read/maintain. Plus, some of that logic should probably be in your business layer, not down in some JavaScript template. In other words, they *force* you to separate your presentation from your logic (which is good).

PS: It is cool that both your client and server-side templates could use the same templating engine. This will make developers on your project much more productive.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scale and requirements of your application, you should take into considerations the following:

1. don't go rampant on Ajax; Ajax is not WebSockets, so use it sparingly. Plus, client-side execution speed is always key; AJAX is slow when compared to dumping as much resources as possible + using them when you need them; for example, you can send to javascript userdata = {name:'xxxx',address;'yyyy', ...}  and using that, instead of requesting name and address via AJAX only when you need them.
2. it is recommended to use a global PHP var $sendData (or something like that) and right after plasting HTML, you send the $sendData with an easy `<script>data = <?php echo json_encode($sendData); ?></script>`
3. javascript templates add up to execution speed. which makes it reasonable to do the alternative, that is, separating everything that is dynamic and caching static resources like javascript functions
4. you can't, and I quote `return a response object containing a compiled javascript template`, not without residing to some server-side javascript engine that does the compile job prior to returning it
5. for your personal welfare, it will always boil down to how fast, easy and painlessly you respond to maintaining the application; there's no point in using super beta experimental frameworks, ports and kits over which you have limited control

Work smart, not hard.
Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into the Distal http://code.google.com/p/distal templating engine.